# Group by modified timestamp and return max value from Elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I'm running Elasticsearch v1.2.2.

I have a collection of documents like this

```
[
  { id: 1, source: { host: 'test.localhost', timestamp: 1407937236, loading_time: 2.841917 } },
  { id: 2, source: { host: 'test.localhost', timestamp: 1407937262, loading_time: 2.009191 } },
  { id: 3, source: { host: 'test.localhost', timestamp: 1407937322, loading_time: 2.084986 } },
  { id: 4, source: { host: 'test.localhost', timestamp: 1407937382, loading_time: 2.869245 } },
  { id: 5, source: { host: 'test.localhost', timestamp: 1407937442, loading_time: 2.559648 } },
  ...
]
```

*(Basically all minutes I run a test against an internal host which returns me the loading time.)*

Now I want to generate an overview graph with:

- timestamps grouped by 30 minutes
- return the maximum loading_time (of that grouping)
- where host is something specific
- between a specific timestamp range
- ordered by timestamp

Since I'm new to Elasticsearch I don't even know if all of that is possible.

In MySQL this would look like this

```
SELECT (FLOOR(`timestamp` / 1800) * 1800) AS timestamp
       MAX(`loading_time`) AS loading_time
FROM `elasticsearch_table`
GROUP BY (FLOOR(`timestamp` / 1800) * 1800)
WHERE `host` = 'test.localhost'
AND `timestamp` BETWEEN 1407937236 AND 1407937442
ORDER BY `timestamp` ASC
```

*(Not sure this MySQL query works, but it should give you an idea of what I want to achieve.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature to use for such computing is called [**aggregations**](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#_structuring_aggregations) in Elasticsearch.

Here follows some aggregations that should suit your need for each step :

- timestamps grouped by 30 minutes => [date_histogram](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation) aggregation with interval at 30m
- return the maximum loading_time (of that grouping) => [max](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html) aggregation on the loading-time.
- where host is something specific => [filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) aggregation with a [term filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html#query-dsl-term-filter) on the **host**.
- between a specific timestamp range => another filter aggregation with a [range](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-filter.html#query-dsl-range-filter) filter.
- ordered by timestamp

The tricky part is to nest the different aggregations correctly. You should make some tests on a small dataset to check that.

Give a try to something like this :

```
GET test/collection/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "filter_by_host":{
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {"term": {"host": "test.localhost"}},
            {"range": {"timestamp": {
              "from": 1407937230000,               
              "to": 1407937400000
            }}}
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "date": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "interval": "2m"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "max_loading_time": {
             "max" : {"field" : "loading_time" }}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The interval is only 2 minutes long, and the range boundaries are chosen only to exclude the fifth document from your dataset, to see it effectively filtering.

The only missing part is the sort : you can't sort on count results.

The request output :

```
{
    ...
   "aggregations": {
      "filter_by_host": {
         "doc_count": 4,
         "date": {
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key_as_string": "2014-08-13T13:40:00.000Z",
                  "key": 1407937200000,
                  "doc_count": 2,
                  "max_loading_time": {
                     "value": 2.841917
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key_as_string": "2014-08-13T13:42:00.000Z",
                  "key": 1407937320000,
                  "doc_count": 2,
                  "max_loading_time": {
                     "value": 2.869245
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, you're a genius! Many thanks!
The only part which was not working for me was the "date_histogram" part.
I changed it to `'histogram': { 'field': 'timestamp', 'interval': 600 }` (600 = 10 minutes). I think this is because I'm working with my own timestamp field.

Comment: You're welcome! The problem with the timestamp can be because it's a timestamp in seconds. While testing, I had to multiply it by 1000 to make it work with date_histogram. However, the histogram aggregation works too :)